# How do I run a local Spark 2.x Session?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

For testing purposes I want to have Spark 2.x run in a local mode. How can I do this? Can I do this? Currently I write in a `main`:

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder
  .appName("RandomForestClassifierExample")
  .getOrCreate()
```

and run the main in IntelliJ, but I get the error

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration
```

I guess I need to have some local instance running or set a local mode or something like that. What should I do exactly?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should configure a `.master(..)` before calling `getOrCreate`:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder
  .master("local")
  .appName("RandomForestClassifierExample")
  .getOrCreate()
```

"local" means all of Spark's components (master, executors) will run locally within your single JVM running this code (very convenient for tests, pretty much irrelevant for real world scenarios). Read more about other "master" options [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#master-urls).